# Incompatible error with gradle on Functions Completable Future

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, executorservice, completable-future

```
public void initateScheduledRequest(long time, Runnable actionRequired) {
    LOGGER.info("Retry Request Initated");
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Executor timeDiff = r -> ses.schedule(() -> executor.execute(r), time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(actionRequired, executor);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        future = future
                .handle((k, v) -> v == null ? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(v)
                        : CompletableFuture.runAsync(actionRequired, timeDiff))
                .thenCompose(
                         (Function<? super CompletableFuture<? extends Object>, ? extends CompletionStage<Void>>) Function
                                .identity());
    }
    LOGGER.info("Retry Done");
}
```

This piece of code is working fine on eclipse but when I am going to build using gradle its giving  error:

> incompatible types: `Function<Object,Object>` cannot be converted to
>   `Function<? super CompletableFuture<? extends Object>,? extends
>   CompletionStage<Void>>.identity())`;

how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you pass to `handle()` can return either a `CompletableFuture<Throwable>` or a `CompletableFuture<Void>`. The only compatible type is thus `CompletableFuture<?>`.

This means that the result of `handle()` is thus a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<?>>`, which you are trying to unwrap using an identity function passed to `thenCompose()`.

This means that `future` to which you are trying to assign this result should be declared as `CompletableFuture<?>`.

Once you do this, it is unfortunately still not possible to use `identity()` for the composition, because the compiler cannot infer the proper generic type for this call and selects the default `Object` which is out of the bounds expected by the cast, or be `thenCompose()` if you remove it.

On the other side, if you try to enforce the actual type with:

```
.thenCompose(Function.<CompletableFuture<?>>identity());
```

Then the compiler is still not able to infer the type variable `U` of `thenCompose()` which does not help either.

However, there is a simple workaround to this problem: just use a lambda expression:

```
.thenCompose(f -> f)
```

So the resulting code would be:

```
CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(actionRequired, executor);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    future = future
            .handle((k, v) -> v == null ? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(v)
                    : CompletableFuture.runAsync(actionRequired, timeDiff))
            .thenCompose(f -> f);
}
```